# React TypeError Accessing JSON Data Dynamically

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, dynamic, typeerror

First off, I am new to Typescript, so this is probably simple.  I am attempting to create a landing page in React for all of my partners on my website.  It is a single page that can pull the partner name out of the URL, and then know exactly what logo to insert, which background image to use, and which marketing labels to use.  I store this data in a JSON file.  But I need to create a string for the company name in the url, and access the data in the JSON file dynamically based on this string.  And Typescript doesn't like it.  It is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headline')
```

So my partner-resource-list.json file looks like the following:

```
{
  "companyA": {
    "logoURL": "https://s3.amazon.com/companyA-logo.svg",
    "backgroundURL": "https://s3.amazon.com/companyA-background.png",
    "headline": "CompanyA Headline!",
    "marketing": "Here's a place for some marketing text.",
    "bullets": ["A bullet list", "Another bullet!"]
  },
  "companyB": {
    "logoURL": "https://s3.amazon.com/companyB-logo.svg",
    "backgroundURL": "https://s3.amazon.com/companyB-background.png",
    "headline": "CompanyB Headline!",
    "marketing": "Here's a place for some marketing text",
    "bullets": ["A bullet list", "Another bullet!"]
  }
}
```

And an abbreviated version of the React page using Typescript looks like this:

```
import { Formik } from "formik";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as partnerData from "./utilities/partner-resource-list.json";

const testString = "companyA";
console.log(partnerData[testString].headline);
```

I need to access the object using bracket notation so that it is dynamic and I can chose which company's data I want to display. But if I run the code as shown above, I get the TypeError listed above.  If I simply get rid of the testString variable and put "companyA" directly inside the brackets next to partnerData, it works fine.  I feel like the "companyA" property in the json file might be set to a type of undefined, and my testString variable is a string.  I don't know if you can change the types pulled in from a JSON file?  But it seriously does not like this and I am at a loss as to what I might be able to do.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you `console.log(partnerData[testString])` what do you get?

Comment: I get no errors in the browser, but the console.log writes out 'undefined'.  If I execute console.log(partnerData["companyA"]), I get the whole object logged